# File download fails with AFNetworking and other frameworks. wifi goes to sleep automatically - objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm downloading files with AFNetworking framework. File downloads well in foreground mode. But when I put my app to background, WiFi goes to sleep automatically after 10 minutes, by iOS, and my AFNetworking request loses connection. In my AppDelegate I have this code to run background task:

```
-(void) runBackgroundTask
{
   if (bgTaskId!=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTaskId];

     UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTaskId];
     [self runBackgroundTask];
}];
   bgTaskId = newTaskId;
}
```

How disable automatic WiFi sleep? If I run music on my app and downloading file - everything is OK. WiFi doesn't disable.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: 10 minute limit was set by Apple. Go and read programming guides on background modes. You cannot fight against it. Cooperate with it.

Comment: I know about that. Read code above please. My background task runs again and again. There are a lot of downloaders in App Store, which downloads files more than 10 minutes in background without interruption.